# Elegant way in Scala to render List of objects(columns) with List attribute(cell values) in a grid?

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections, playframework-2.3, scala-2.11

What is the "best" way to render a List of model objects(matrix) in a Scala template such as:

```
public class Column extends Model {

    public String columnLabel;

    @OneToMany
    public List cells;
}

public class Cell extends Model {
    public String rowLabel; //index
    public BigDecimal value;
}
```

For the sake of this question, cells.size() and rowLabel are consistent for all column objects. The controller returns a List[Column] to the view. I have tried to convert the List to an Array with a helper:

```
@matrix(list: List[Column]):Array = @{

    var rowCount = list.head.values.size()
    var colCount = list.size()
    var m = Array.ofDim[String](rowCount,colCount)
    for (i <- 0 to rowCount-1) {
        for ( j <- 0 to colCount-1) {
            matrix(i)(j) = list(j).cells(i).value.toString();
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

and then in the view:

```
<div>
    @for(i <- 1 to currentPage.getList.head.values.size()) {
        <div class="row">
            @for(j <- 1 to currentPage.getList.size()) {
                <div class="col-md-1">@matrix(currentPage.getList)(i)(j)</div>
             }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

but of course this is only extracting the matrix values and not the column or row labels.

Is there some Scala array goodness that can be used on the List of Lists? Efficiency is important as the array size will be approx. 20 columns x 2000 rows. Or is it a better approach to have the controller return the matrix rows explicitly rather than try to convert them in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for-comprehensions instead of imperative-style cycles, they are more natural in Scala.
And for your task, there are many ways to do it, one of them is like this:

```
// transform your data to grid, i.e. Map((row,col) -> value). 
// Do this outside the template and pass the result (so that you get the immutable map as a template input)
val toGrid = {
  currentPage.getList.map{ col => col.cells.map(cell => 
    (cell.rowLabel, col.columnLabel, cell.value)
  )}.flatten.map{ case (row, col, value) => ((row,col)->value) }.toMap
}

@rows = @{toGrid.map{ case ((row,col),value) => row }.toSet.toList.sorted}
@columns = @{toGrid.map{ case ((row,col),value) => col }.toSet.toList.sorted}


<div>
@for(row -> rows) {
    <div class="row">
    @for(col -> columns) {
     <div>@toGrid.get(row,col).getOrElse("")</div> //if you might have missing rows/cols
    }
    </div>
}
</div>
```

UPDATE. If, for some reason, you can't have Scala class outside the template, then the following should perform better(assuming there are no gaps in rows or columns):

```
@data = @{currentPage.getList}

@triplets = @{data.map{
  col => col.cells.map(cell => (cell.rowLabel,col.columnLabel,cell.value)
)}.flatten

@rows = @{triplets.groupBy(_._1).map{ case (row,cols) => 
          (row, cols.map{ case (row,col,value) => (col,value) })
}}

<div>
@for((row,cols) -> rows.sortBy(_._1)) {
  <div class="row">
  @for((col,value) -> cols.sortBy(_._1)){
    <div>@value</div>
  }
  </div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: I think that will give me a set of rows for each column object rather than render a matrix with common rowLabels - or more specifically rows with values from each column.

Comment: In order to get the actual triplet I had to add `.map{ case (col, (row,value)) => (col, row, value)}` to the zip but am now running into an issue with a compilation error on the groupBy: `constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3)
 required: List[(String, String, java.math.BigDecimal)]`

Comment: I have simplified it now, using  a different approach. It is quite preferable that the toGrid transformation is done outside the template, otherwise it will be called as many times as there are elements in your grid. (And it should be val, not def)

Comment: This definitely works, but as you say it performs poorly in the template, as expected. Any hints on how to create a Map((row,col) -> value) in Java?

Comment: Can't you have Scala class?

Comment: Added the version for when you can't have Scala class (with the restriction that there are no gaps in rows or columns)